# MySQL Not allowing delete even though FK relationship ON DELETE CASCADE set

Tags: mysql, database, cascading-deletes

I am working on a project that makes use of a MySQL Database to store snippets of code for use on multiple websites. For each content snippet I also keep an edit history table, to which I add a record every time a snippet is updated. Occasionally it will be desirable to delete a snippet completely, and any associated edit history. When setting up the DB, I set up the foreign key relationship to ON DELETE CASCADE so that deleting the snippet will automatically delete the history. However, I am getting the following error:

> Error in query: delete from SNIPPET where id = 1. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`universal_content_repository/SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORY`, CONSTRAINT `fk_SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORYRelationship13` FOREIGN KEY (`snippet_id`) REFERENCES `SNIPPET` (`id`))

Here is the code I use to create the DB as well as the relationships:

```
/*Schema universal_content_repository*/
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `universal_content_repository`
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE `universal_content_repository`;

CREATE TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`USER` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Stores the ID for the User.',
`username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
`first_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`last_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`is_active` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
`password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`is_admin` BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`prefers_wysiwyg` BIT DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) COMMENT 'Stores information about all Users for the Universal Content Repository.' ENGINE=INNODB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`content` TEXT NOT NULL,
`created_by` INT UNSIGNED,
`wysiwyg_editable` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
`is_enabled` BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) COMMENT 'Guarantees that no two snippets may have the same name or ID.' ENGINE=INNODB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`IMAGE` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`url` TEXT NOT NULL,
`alt` VARCHAR(32),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`IMAGE_IN_SNIPPET` (
`rel_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`snippet_id` INT UNSIGNED,
`image_id` INT UNSIGNED,
`position` INT COMMENT 'Stores the position of the image within the snippet, as notated in the snippet as [index]',
PRIMARY KEY (`rel_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORY` (
`revision_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`editing_user` INT UNSIGNED,
`snippet_id` INT UNSIGNED,
`old_contents` TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stores the old contents of the snippet.',
`edit_date` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stores the DateTime of the edit.',
PRIMARY KEY (`revision_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SESSION` (
`id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stores the Session ID',
`access` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`data` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`USER` ADD UNIQUE `Identifiers` (`id`,`username`);

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET` ADD UNIQUE `identifiers` (`title`,`id`);

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_SNIPPETRelationship8` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `universal_content_repository`.`USER`(`id`) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`IMAGE_IN_SNIPPET` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_IMAGE_IN_SNIPPETRelationship10` FOREIGN KEY (`snippet_id`) REFERENCES `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET`(`id`) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`IMAGE_IN_SNIPPET` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_IMAGE_IN_SNIPPETRelationship11` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `universal_content_repository`.`IMAGE`(`id`) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORY` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORYRelationship12` FOREIGN KEY (`editing_user`) REFERENCES `universal_content_repository`.`USER`(`id`) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORY` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_SNIPPET_EDIT_HISTORYRelationship13` FOREIGN KEY (`snippet_id`) REFERENCES `universal_content_repository`.`SNIPPET`(`id`) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If you want to see a graphical representation of the DB, you can see it at [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com/a/VYFrg).
For those without a SchemaBank account, here is the ER:
[image: UCR Schema]

Any ideas?

Comment: Schemabank requires a login, so it's useless.

Comment: I went ahead and added a png for you.

Comment: I have no idea why it's doing this. I can give you a workaround in the form of an AFTER DELETE TRIGGER that deletes all `snippet_edit_history` but that just routes around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is right.

If it's practical, dump that database and restore it onto a different server as a test. If INNODB and MySQL internal states have gotten out of sync, that should give you a well-behaved database on the server you restore to.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to move the DB to another server, however I did work around the issue using a BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER. I'm wondering if perhaps I should file a bug report with MySQL?

Comment: Can you restore it on the same server without clobbering your existing database?

Comment: No, but since I'm in development there is only test data in the DB so clobbering the DB is no problem. Deleting the database and starting from scratch with it was the first thing I did after looking through my code and not finding any issues, and my problem persisted there as well.